# how to execute a command passed into a batch file

Tags: batch-file, whitespace, double-quotes

What I would like to do is write a generic execute command wrapper "method" in a batch file.  Here is an example of the method I want:

```
:EXEC_CMD
set cmd=%~1
echo Executuing cmd: %cmd%
CALL %cmd%
rem *** check some stuff and end
```

This works for simple commands but when the commands I want to execute has parameters and they require quotes, then things do not work so well:

cmd to execute:

```
:EXEC_CMD "test.bat "arg1" "arg 2" "a r g 3""
```

output:

```
Executing cmd: test.bat "arg1" "arg
```

what is the best way to get the above to execute any command I give it?  I tried escaping the nested double quotes and placing quotes in different spots but nothing has worked so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
:EXEC_CMD
set cmd=%*
echo Executuing cmd: %cmd%
CALL %cmd%
rem *** check some stuff and end
```

Comment: I hate it when the answer is so simple! Thank you for answering such a simple question.  Using %* did not even occur to me.